# Running Scripts on Multiple Servers PHP

Tags: php, linux

At work we have been assigned an additional server because the load for our current server is to much.

What I want to do now is have all my PHP Scripts on one Server ( Server 1) ran  from another (server 2) to allow less stress on (server 1). Also I want to be able to have sub domain for server 2  on the same domain for server 1.

If anyone could point me in the right direction as to what I should be doing I would greatly appreciate this.

Thank you for any help.

James

Comment: for the subdomain, you need to go to http://serverfault.com/

Comment: Thank you for the response am I right in thinking DNS Clustering is way the forward to resolve my other problems?

Comment: As far as i know, can't you include files with an url (ip or not). so mayby can you use symbolic links to achief it... But i think it's better to upgrade your server, or separate multiple site's (so site a on server 1, site b on server 2..... and then do some magic with domains to sort it al out...)

Comment: @TWCrap: This wouldn't be a good fit for SF as it lacks any information which would be useful to us.

Comment: @Iain, why is the subdomain part usefull for us then?!?

Comment: @TWCrap: I didn't say it was. I just said the question isn't a good fit for SF - http://serverfault.com/questions/434030/running-scripts-on-multiple-servers-php

Comment: @Iain, you're right, that what's been asked, doesn't fit right there. But i said that the subdomain would probably fit there better ;-)

Answer (score 3):

If you're running more than just your website on server 1 I would recommend that you split up the responsibilities of the servers so that the two of them get a somewhat equal load, otherwise it seems that a loadbalancer would be the way to go.

I can't really see the purpose of including files from server 1 to server 2 since that will incur yet more load on server 1 while transferring the files from 1 to 2.

But I agree with the comment saying that you should go to serverfault, they are/should be more knowledgeable about these kind of questions.